# Next.js api router throws 404

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js13

I am new to Next.js and I'm having trouble getting my API to work properly. I've set up a test endpoint at `src/app/api/hello.ts` with a basic response. However, when I try to access `example.com/api/hello`, I'm getting a 404 page instead of the expected response. Can anyone help me troubleshoot this issue? Here's the code for my endpoint:

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'

export default function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  res.status(200).json({ name: 'John Doe' })
}
```

Note: I use auth0 for authentication and the `/api/auth/[auth0]/` works just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you are using the new [app router](https://nextjs.org/docs/app) of next.js 13. When using app router with api routes, you have to follow the [naming convention for api routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/router-handlers): `app/api/[ROUTE_PATH]/route.ts`. So try to move the contents of your current route handler to `src/app/api/hello/route.ts`. Using the new app router, the [signature](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/router-handlers#convention) of the route handler changed as well: instead of one handler exported as default, you will have to export a function for each HTTP method your route supports (e.g. GET, POST, PUT, ...), which accepts a single parameter of type `Request`. I hope this helped you!

Comment: Thanks for answering, using route.ts worked. I like the new app router but I find it hard to find a tutorial or example for Next.js 13.  (note for people in the future: if u use the new app router you also need to use an other function, for each method you need a different function for more information see the [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/router-handlers#convention)

Comment: you have to be extra careful on the filename, I was struggling until I found out I mistaken `route` for `routes`

Answer (score 1):

This is a follow-up to Fatorice's response. Here is what you need to change:

The following (page router):

```
// Filename: pages/api/hello.ts

import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

type ResponseData = {
  message: string;
};

export default function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse<ResponseData>
) {
  res.status(200).json({ message: "Hello from Next.js!" });
}
```

Needs to be changed to (app router):

```
// Filename: app/api/hello/route.ts

function requestHandler(_request: Request): Response {
  return Response.json({ message: "Hello from Next.js!" });
}

export { requestHandler as GET };
```

If you are using a version of TypeScript < 5.2, you need to change the signature an usage to:

```
// Filename: app/api/hello/route.ts

import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

function requestHandler(_request: NextRequest): NextResponse {
  return NextResponse.json({ message: "Hello from Next.js!" });
}

export { requestHandler as GET };
```

These types also provide some additional features that do not come with the standard `Request` and `Response` types.

> #### Extended NextRequest and NextResponse APIs
>
> In addition to supporting native `Request` and `Response`. Next.js extends them with `NextRequest` and `NextResponse` to provide convenient helpers for advanced use cases.